# Invertibility of Product implies invertibility of factors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say $C=AB$ where $A,B,C$ are all $n\times n$ matrices.  It's easy to show that if $A$ and $B$ are invertible then $C$ is invertible --> $C^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

Does the converse hold?  That is, if $C$ is invertible, can we conclude that $A$ and $B$ are invertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

One easy proof is that $\det(C) = \det(A)\det(B)$, and $\det(C) \ne 0$ so $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$ must not equal $0$ either.

---

Another way to figure it out is think of the linear transformation $T_C$ defined by $T_C(x) = Cx = ABx$.  The fact that $C$ is invertible means that $T_C$ is bijective.  This implies that $T_B$ is injective and $T_A$ is surjective *at least* (more things are in fact implied but this is all we need).  Recall if the linear transformation on $\Bbb R^n$ is [injective *or* surjective then it must be bijective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354629/a-linear-transformation-tv-to-v-is-one-to-one-if-and-only-if-it-is-onto).  Thus $A$ and $B$ are invertible.

---

I can give more proofs if you require.  Do you already know the facts that I referenced for these?  If not, I'm going to need to know exactly what you *do know*.

Comment: I didn't think to use the determinant.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem. :-)